# vs code C# ошибка при запуске: "ConfigurationDone"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, отладка, launcher

Решил начать учить `С#` , установил всё что нужно для него. По итогу создаю тестовый консольный проект в vs code через `dotnet new console -n "HelloWorld"` и вследствие запуска выводится данное сообщение:
Уже который час не могу понять в чём дело.[image]

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Comment: windows 10 home ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, установлена не та версия .NET или же он просто неправильно установлен.

Если у вас Windows 10 x64, то удалите существующий .NET (сделать это можно через панель управления -> программы и компоненты) и скачайте SoftwareDevelopmentKit [отсюда](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download).

Так же, если не получается в среде разработки запустить код на "горячие клавиши", то попробуйте запустить через команду `dotnet run`.